# SQLite: Update field with result of another query

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a database with one table, let's say 'tablename'. Now, I want the first column of that table, named 'text' to be updated with the text it containts PLUS some new text which comes as result from another query executed over 'tablename2'. So, I want something like this:

```
UPDATE tablename SET text="current text" + (SELECT * FROM tablename2 where ID=12);
```

If 'text' value is '`Result not available`' I want to *append* ' `here`', so that the field value is '`Result not available here`'

How is this possible? Thanks

Comment: see this [Update query in Sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22956377/1718223) answer , solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

Try the concatenation operator (||):

```
UPDATE tablename SET text='current text'||(SELECT * FROM tablename2 where ID=12);
```

And I'm not sure, but you should use ' instead of " .

Comment: You're definitely correct about the quote character and the concatenation operator, but the rest of the SQL smelly fishy. (Not that that's your fault though.)

Comment: ' only a single result allowed for a SELECT that is part of an expression'

Answer (score 1):

I probably misunderstood your question, but let's try:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/959e5/2

```
UPDATE Table1
SET text = text || 
    CASE
      WHEN text = 'Result not available' THEN ' here'
      ELSE (SELECT text FROM Table2 where id = 12)
    END;
```